# Using PDFBox or something else, is it possible to know if a pdf contains no scanned pages?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm looking for a solution to detect if a pdf document contains some non-searchable text, I'm thinking about a scenario where a multi-page pdf contains some plain text pages, with or without images it doesn't matter, and one or some pages containing non-searchable texts.

So I would like a method returning true/false which is able to detect if a pdf contains some non-searchable text (or viceversa), in your opinion is it possible with PDFBox or something else?

Thx

Comment: To check whether there is non-searchable text, you'll essentially have to apply OCR to the rendered page, extract the searchable text, and compare those texts. Beware, there might be some differences between extracted and OCR'ed text even for completely searchable PDFs.

Comment: Yes but I would like to know in advance, because if I know there is non-searchable text then I would submit that pdf to an OCR solution, saying differently I don't want send a full searchable-text pdf to an OCR, it would be unuseful and resource consuming, am I wrong?

Comment: Well, you can of course *guess* that if there is no (are only very little) searchable text on a page, it is likely that there is non-searchable text while if there is a lot of searchable text, there likely is no non-searchable text. But this is a mere *guess*. If you need to be sure, you have to OCR and compare.

Comment: Thanks but how do you guess if there is no searchable-text on a page, does PDFBox have such a feature? For example I know there is PDFTextStripper, so if given a page it returns no text I could consider that page is non-searchable? Thx

Comment: The stripper indeed extracts the text which usually can be searched.